# NameError: uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby

Given the following code:

```
module Backup
  module Destination
    class Base
      def initialize
        puts 'Base'
      end
    end
  end
end

module Backup
  module Destination
    class Test < Base
      def initialize
        puts 'Test'
        super
      end
    end
  end
end

Backup::Destination::Test.new
```

This works as expected, outputting:

```
Test
Base
```

However if I split things up like this:

```
# lib/backup.rb
require_relative 'backup/destination/base'

module Backup; end


# lib/backup/destination/base.rb
require_relative 'test'

module Backup
  module Destination
    class Base
      def initialize
        puts 'Base'
      end
    end
  end
end


# lib/backup/destination/test.rb
module Backup
  module Destination
    class Test < Base
      def initialize
        puts 'Test'
        super
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And execute with the following (from irb):

```
require_relative 'lib/backup'
```

I get this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Backup::Destination::Base
    from /lib/backup/destination/test.rb:3:in `<module:Destination>'
    from /lib/backup/destination/test.rb:2:in `<module:Backup>'
    from /lib/backup/destination/test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /lib/backup/destination/base.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    from /lib/backup/destination/base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /lib/backup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    from /lib/backup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from (irb):1:in `require_relative'
```

What am I missing?

Note: I couldn't post the above without adding more details. Stupid feature because in this case code is worth a thousand words. (this text allowed the question to be posted)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are requiring `test.rb` before your `Base` class is defined. One possible solution is to move your require to the bottom of `base.rb`.

Another possible solution is to remove your require from `base` and require both files in the correct order from `backup`.

Comment: Thanks. I mistakenly thought the files were required before anything was executed.

Answer (score 0):

Made the following changes to fix the problem:

```
# lib/backup.rb
require_relative 'backup/destination/base'
require_relative 'backup/destination/test'

module Backup; end
```

And removed the `require_relative` statement from `lib/backup/destination/base.rb`. This fixed the order of the `require_relative` statements. I mistakenly thought the files were required before anything was executed.